# Cannot open Display Settings

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Dell Presicion. I plugged in second monitor with no problems but I cannot open Display settings. I got an error:

`libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libEGL warning: DRI3: Screen seems not DRI3 capable
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate`

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Installing NVidia drivers helped

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux